# Exporting Excel ranges on different tabs as a pdf in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I've tried the below, but what it does it apply the range I specify in Sheet1 to ALL the other sheets. I've also tried using ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select for each sheet, but that includes extraneous cells that I don't want displayed in the PDF. Does anyone have any ideas? I'm running Office 365 on Windows.

```
Sub SaveRangesAsPDF()

   Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1:L42").Select
   Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1:G35").Select
  

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select
   Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").Value, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
      True
End Sub
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to print selections on multiple sheets. You can choose one of:

1. Selection on a single sheet.
2. Active sheet(s) - an active sheet or selected sheets considering the printing area or not.
3. Entire workbook - all sheets considering the printing area or not.

The solution for you is to define the printing area on each sheet and print selected sheets.

```
Sheet1.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$L$42"
Sheet2.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$G$35"
Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").Value, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
  IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
  True
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to respond. If I look at the page break previews on each page, they're correctly specified. Do I have to change the underlying code to reference just the "page break selection" then?

Comment: You question is not clear for me. But you need to include everything you need to print into printing areas. All page breaks will be considered as they appear.

Comment: Thank you so much. Solved! It looks like it all came down to using PageSetup.PrintArea rather than Selections. Thanks again for taking the time to reply.